# Using Carbon in Cocoa Apps?

Tags: macos, cocoa, macos-carbon

I've asked a more specific question [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31612753/current-status-of-global-hot-key-shortcuts) but it's rolling amongst tumbleweeds.

Maybe I can get an answer to a more general question:

Carbon being deprecated and 32-bit–only, how bad of an idea is it to call Carbon APIs in an otherwise fully 64-bit, modern Cocoa app?

- Will it negate whatever improvements 64-bit execution brings?
- Could it jeoprardize the MAS review process and contribute to an app getting rejected from the Mac App Store?

I understand that you should probably not choose to do it, I'm talking about a situation where `import Carbon` is the only way to achieve something. Is the feature still worth it at that point?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Current status of global "hot key" shortcuts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31612753/current-status-of-global-hot-key-shortcuts)

Comment: Dude, it's not a possible duplicate, it's my question which I linked to myself in the first line of my question.

Comment: I welcome an explanation of any other way I could've handled this. The other question had no answers, so “This question may already have an answer here:” is just incorrect.

Comment: alter your first question.

Comment: That wouldn't have gotten it the attention it got from being bumped. I will gladly delete the other question if that makes you happier.

Comment: Look at my history. I am not a spammer. If I made a mistake it wasn't intentional.

Comment: and btw: I don't like to be called "dude" by people I don't know.

Comment: I think this should get arbitrated. You are not acting in good faith.

Comment: And I’m sorry if I offended you by saying "Dude," but I didn't mean that you were a dude or a stoner or anything else implied by that. I used that word in its fully canonized meaning as an interjection, as [an expression of shock or other strong feeling](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/dude?s=t).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply can't call Carbon functions from a 64-bit app.  The link will fail (if the compile didn't already fail).  At best you could put the Carbon stuff in a helper tool that you talk to with a pipe or something.  And yes, Apple has said that using deprecated APIs can result in your app being rejected by the Mac App Store.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But then how do apps in the App Store like OmniFocus and Fantastical do global Hot Keys when it's not something available in Cocoa?

Comment: As far as I can tell from the 10.7 SDK headers, `RegisterEventHotKey` is one of the small bits of Carbon that actually *is* available in 64 bits.  At least, a bunch of other functions in the CarbonEvents.h header are marked with `#if !__LP64__` and that one isn't.  But one could implement a global hot key using a Quartz event tap instead; see `CGEventTapCreate` for instance.

Comment: Thank you, that's extremely useful. Both the answer and how you got at it.